# $S_{xx}$ for simple regression - T test and Confidence interval for mean response?

Tags: regression, self-study

I have an odd problem with my homework involving regression analysis. Please see the output highlighted in red below. For the test statistic, $S_{xx}$ is computed as 11.2896. (3.36 squared).  Within the confidence interval below that, sxx suddenly becomes $165901^{2}$ .... is there something about $S_{xx}$ for a confidence interval that changes this amount? Should Sxx stay the same?

Thank you
  [image]

[image]